# How does the "Using" statement translate from C# to VB?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

For example:

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();

byte[] buffer = GetHugeByteArray(); // from some external source
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer, false))
{
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmap.EndInit();
    bitmap.Freeze();
}
```

Can you tell me any more about `using`?

**Edit:**

As was discussed in the comments of JaredPar's post, this question is more concerned with an implementation of `Using` in VS2003.  It was pointed out that `Using` was not introduced until .NET 2.0 (VS2005).  JaredPar posted an equivalent workaround.

Comment: Search for "using keyword C#" or some variation of.

Comment: From the **Visual Basic Programming Guide:** [How to: Dispose of a System Resource (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wydd5hkd.aspx)

Comment: For those looking for the equivalent of the using directive ie.
using System.Net; the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134472/vb-net-equivalent-to-cs-using-directive

Comment: Using in VB.net can also do compound entries where C# requires two separate lines.  Also, implied types can be used, i.e.: 
Using x = New MemoryStream(buffer1), y = New MemoryStream(buffer2)
.....
End Using

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Using has virtually the same syntax in VB as C#, assuming you're using .NET 2.0 or later (which implies the VB.NET v8 compiler or later).  Basically, just remove the braces and add a "End Using"

```
Dim bitmap as New BitmapImage()
Dim buffer As Byte() = GetHugeByteArrayFromExternalSource()
Using stream As New MemoryStream(buffer, false)
    bitmap.BeginInit()
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
    bitmap.StreamSource = stream
    bitmap.EndInit()
    bitmap.Freeze()
End Using
```

You can get the full documentation here

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh(VS.80).aspx

**EDIT**

If you're using VS2003 or earlier you'll need the below code.  The using statement was not introduced until VS 2005, .NET 2.0 ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_2005#Visual_Basic_2005_.28VB_8.0.29)).  Thanks Chris!.  The following is equivalent to the using statement.

```
Dim bitmap as New BitmapImage()
Dim buffer As Byte() = GetHugeByteArrayFromExternalSource()
Dim stream As New MemoryStream(buffer, false)
Try
    bitmap.BeginInit()
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
    bitmap.StreamSource = stream
    bitmap.EndInit()
    bitmap.Freeze()
Finally
    DirectCast(stream, IDisposable).Dispose()
End Try
```

Comment: Which version of VB was this added? I'm working with some legacy code and Visual Studio 2003 doesn't seem to be picking up on it.

Comment: @hypoxide, the using statement has been around since the original VB.Net AFAIK.  I changed the code to get rid of a couple of items that weren't available till later versions.  Can you try that and if you see any errors add them here?

Comment: The Using statement in VB was not introduced until VS2005.  It is not available in prior versions.

Comment: Chris is correct: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_2005#Visual_Basic_2005_.28VB_8.0.29

Comment: Also note that for Namespace references and alias declaration C# using is the same as VB's Imports.

Answer (score 5):

Its important to point out that using is actually compiled into various lines of code, similar to lock, etc.

From the C# language specification....
A using statement of the form

```
using (ResourceType resource = expression) statement
```

corresponds to one of two possible expansions. When `ResourceType` is a value type, the expansion is

```
{
    ResourceType resource = expression;
    try {
        statement;
    }
    finally {
        ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, when ResourceType is a reference type, the expansion is

```
{
    ResourceType resource = expression;
    try {
        statement;
    }
    finally {
        if (resource != null) ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
    }
}
```

(end language specification snippet)

Basically, at compile time its converted into that code.  There is no method called using, etc.  I tried to find similar stuff in the vb.net language specification but I couldn't find anything, presumably it does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3):

That would be something like this:

```
Dim bitmap As New BitmapImage()
Dim buffer As Byte() = GetHugeByteArray()
Using stream As New MemoryStream(buffer, False)
    bitmap.BeginInit()
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
    bitmap.StreamSource = stream
    bitmap.EndInit()
    bitmap.Freeze()
End Using
```

Answer (score 3):

The key point is that the class being "used" must implement the IDisposable interface.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `using`(C#) and `Using` (VB) have an extremely important difference. And at least for me now, it can defeat the purpose of `Using`.

```
Imports System.IO
Class Program

    Private Shared sw As StreamWriter

    Private Shared Sub DoSmth()
        sw.WriteLine("foo")
    End Sub

    Shared Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
        Using sw = New StreamWriter("C:\Temp\data.txt")
            DoSmth()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

You'll get NullReferenceException as in VB `Using` redefines the member class variable while in C# it doesn't!

Of course, maybe I missing something..

Comment: it doesn't redefine the member variable, it overrides it within the scope of the method.  It still exists, and has the same name