# What is the VB.NET equivalent to C#'s 'using' block

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am coding in VB.NET.

Currently, I am enclosing object initialization and usage in a Try/Catch block and then tear it down (dispose, close, set to nothing) in the Finally block.  The problem is, a C# 'using' block is so easy to use and would clean things up in my code.

Is there a VB.NET equivalent?  Or is my Finally block tear-down solution the only way?

Comment: Wow!  Don't I feel like an idiot.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's the same, it's just:

```
Using conn As New SqlConnection
    ....
End Using
```

Answer (score 7):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh(VS.80).aspx

```
Public Sub setbigbold(ByVal c As Control)
    Using nf As New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12.0F, _
        System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)

        c.Font = nf
        c.Text = "This is 12-point Arial bold"
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: This definitely needs a better example.  This is a guaranteed ObjectDisposedException.

Comment: @crackedcornjimmy: Yes. The font is assigned to a property in the control, and then it's disposed. When the control tries to use the font, the actual GDI font is gone.

Comment: @Guffa: So the Font property doesn't make a copy of the font and dispose of its old one?  How is one supposed to keep track of who owns control fonts?

Comment: It should come as no surprise that the page cited above by @xandercoded has moved. The new address is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement.

Answer (score 6):

Er, `Using` ... `End Using`

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh(VS.80).aspx) for more info

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887831/vb-how-does-the-using-statement-translate-from-c-to-vb) is another StackOverflow question that deals with the exact same issue.  If I'm not mistaken it's used in a very similar, if not the exact same, way as in C# though.

Hope this helps!