# Which is faster - A Using block or Try/Catch/Finally

Tags: vb.net, performance, using

This is a followup question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631359/what-is-the-vb-net-equivalent-to-cs-using-block)

Should I stick with the Try/Catch/Finally construct, or go with the Using construct?

Sample Code for Try/Catch/Finally:

```
Dim oRequest As WebRequest
Dim oResponse As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
Dim dataStream As Stream = Nothing
Dim reader As StreamReader = Nothing
Dim responseFromServer As String

Try
        sNewCustomerURL = NewCustomerQueryStringPrepare()

    'make the call to the webservice to add a new customer
    oRequest = WebRequest.Create(sNewCustomerURL)

    oRequest = CType(oRequesC, HttpWebRequest)
    oRequest.Method = "GET"
    oResponse = CType(oRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    dataStream = oResponse.GetResponseStream()
    reader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
    responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd()

        Dim xml As New XmlDocument()
    xml.LoadXml(responseFromServer)
    Dim node As XmlNodeList = xml.GetElementsByTagName("SUCCESS")
    Dim value = CBool(node(0).InnerText)

    'do stuff               


Catch ex As Exception

       'process exception

Finally

    'do cleanup
    oRequest = Nothing
    If Not oResponse Is Nothing Then
        oResponse.Close()
    End If
    oResponse = Nothing
    If Not reader Is Nothing Then
        reader.Close()
    End If
    reader = Nothing
    If Not dataStream Is Nothing Then
        dataStream.Flush()
        dataStream.Close()
    End If
    dataStream = Nothing
End Try
```

I know what the code would need to be for the Using construct.  I just want to know if using the Using construct would be faster comparing clock cycles.

Comment: The `using` tag much faster. Saved me about 5 seconds of typing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There won't be a performance difference. `using` is expanded by the compiler to a try/finally block.

You will see that the following two methods compile to identical IL.

```
void SampleWithUsing()
{
    using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream())
    {
        s.WriteByte(1);
    }
}

void SampleWithTryFinally()
{
    MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();
    try
    {
        s.WriteByte(1);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (s != null) s.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The IL generated in the first case is:

```
.method private hidebysig instance void  SampleWithUsing() cil managed
{
  // Code size       26 (0x1a)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream s)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  .try
  {
    IL_0006:  ldloc.0
    IL_0007:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0008:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.Stream::WriteByte(uint8)
    IL_000d:  leave.s    IL_0019
  }  // end .try
  finally
  {
    IL_000f:  ldloc.0
    IL_0010:  brfalse.s  IL_0018
    IL_0012:  ldloc.0
    IL_0013:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
    IL_0018:  endfinally
  }  // end handler
  IL_0019:  ret
} // end of method Program::SampleWithUsing
```

In the second case with a try/finally in C# we get:

```
.method private hidebysig instance void  SampleWithTryFinally() cil managed
{
  // Code size       26 (0x1a)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] class [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream s)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.MemoryStream::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  .try
  {
    IL_0006:  ldloc.0
    IL_0007:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0008:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.Stream::WriteByte(uint8)
    IL_000d:  leave.s    IL_0019
  }  // end .try
  finally
  {
    IL_000f:  ldloc.0
    IL_0010:  brfalse.s  IL_0018
    IL_0012:  ldloc.0
    IL_0013:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.Stream::Dispose()
    IL_0018:  endfinally
  }  // end handler
  IL_0019:  ret
} // end of method Program::SampleWithTryFinally
```

Comment: You're missing the catch in there.

Comment: @jojaba: Well, I decided to go without catch in the example for simplicity. If you expect the body of the using statement to throw you might add a try/catch. But please note that for a fair comparison you would have to add the catch to both methods, i.e. add a catch to the try/finally version *and* add a try/catch block inside or outside the using statement as well.

Answer (score 2):

`using` compiles into `try`/`catch`/`finally`. I really can't see there being any semantical or performance difference, as long as you properly dispose your object in the case of a manual `try`/`catch`.

In any case, go with `using`, seeing as it does cleanups automagically (actually in the `finally` clause) for you. Even if there is a performance difference, it is likely so minimal that you have better places to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

I have to believe that using versus try/catch is not going to make any difference performance wise relative to the code you are running inside those constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Try/Catch/Finally is faster.

1) 6.638 sec : using tag
2) 6.265 sec : try/catch/finally

I ran this about a dozen times. Try/Catch/Finally always came out on top.

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0; i < 50000000; i++)
{
    using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream())
    {
        s.WriteByte(1);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Subtract(start) + " seconds");
start = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0; i < 50000000; i++)
{
    MemoryStream s = null;
    try
    {
        s = new MemoryStream();
        s.WriteByte(1);
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        if (s != null) s.Dispose();
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Subtract(start) + " seconds");
```

Comment: The benchmark has some issues. The most important ones are: Use a `Stopwatch` for measuring and not `DateTime.Now`. `Stopwatch` uses a performance counter and gives you higher precision. Then, run the code without measuring first, there might be some warm-up time that your sample measured.

Comment: In fact, you will get the opposite result if you put the try/finally for-loop first in your code and then measure the using loop.