# hide datagridview if there is no data in rows in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Hello i have created a search box and the data is fetched in datagrid view if any thing is typed in the text box , but my problem is when some thing typed is not in the database then also the datagridview is visible . i want ot hide the gridview if the data is not available in database .

```
If (txtpname.Text <> "") Then
        Try
            con = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            con.Open()
            Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
            Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim sql As String
            Dim s As String
            s = txtpname.Text
            sql = "SELECT product_name as `Product` , rate as `Rate`,category as `Category`, product_id as `pid` FROM products where product_name like '" & (s) & "%' AND deleted='N' order by product_id ;"
            adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            dgvitmsearch.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            dgvitmsearch.Columns("Product").Width = 220
            dgvitmsearch.Columns("Rate").Visible = False
            dgvitmsearch.Columns("Category").Width = 148
            dgvitmsearch.Columns("pid").Visible = False
            con.Close()


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("error found")
        End Try
```

this above function  is called in txtpname_TextChanged

Comment: Please use Using block (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631359/what-is-the-vb-net-equivalent-to-cs-using-block) when you are working with IDisposable objects such as OleDbConnection (so that they will dispose even if an exception happens)

Answer (score 1):

check if datagridview has rows count<0 and if not hide it. add this after specifying datasource.

```
if dgvitmsearch.rows.count=0 then 

dgvitmsearch.visible=false

end if
```

this will do work

Comment: give it before `con.close`

Comment: break and check if visible is true even after passing through that code.also pls change `dgvitmsearch.rows.count<0` to `dgvitmsearch.rows.count=0`.check updated code

Comment: i checked the count in each step the msgbox is showing the correct count only the dgvitemsearch.visible=false statement is not working .

Comment: thanks .now its working like charm .
 changed to dgvitmsearch.rows.count=0.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to check whether your `dataset(ds)`'s table `ds.Tables` have rows or not and write an `IF` condition just before filling the `datagrid` like below

```
If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

'fill datagrid with your dataset

else

'change visibility here(false)

End If
```

the actual code should write like:

```
  If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        dgvitmsearch.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        dgvitmsearch.Columns("Product").Width = 220
        dgvitmsearch.Columns("Rate").Visible = False
        dgvitmsearch.Columns("Category").Width = 148
        dgvitmsearch.Columns("pid").Visible = False
  Else
        dgvitmsearch.visible = False
  End If
```